# Structure of page is getting changed while zoom in or zoom out

Tags: css, html

I have created the following sample code in my sample.html file-

```
<div Class="Frame" Style="left:20.1637500000001pt; top:730.2pt; width:348.1125pt; height:70.8pt; position:absolute; background-color:transparent;">
          <p Style="text-align:justify; text-align-last:left">
            <span Style="height:9.384765625pt; width:348.1125pt;" class="ln">
              <span Style="font-size:10pt; font-family:F0; letter-spacing:0em; color:rgb(0,0,0)">Lendellaborum ipsum quiae quaeculpa voleseque elluptat. Latur moluptatiunt eicilit et ut aut quis</span>
            </span>
          </p>
</div>
```

When I open it in browser and then make zoom in or zoom out; some of last few words are getting moved to next line.

Does any one know how to avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you actually have those fractional units in your source code, they are going to cause variations as they are rounded by the browser.

Comment: Now checked with rounded values; but still problem is not solved

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which part of your HTML that shouldn't wrap (I'm guessing in the following example the `<span>` with the `ln` class) using the CSS `white-space` property should do the trick.

### Example

```css
span.ln{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```